# Object literal may only specify known properties Angular/TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an error message:

```
Type '{ quantity: number; }' is not assignable to type 
'Partial<EditOrderConfirmModalComponent>'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 
'quantity' does not exist in type 'Partial<EditOrderConfirmModalComponent>'.
```

[Error message - VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQOt5.jpg)

I don't understand where is the problem?

The method is like this:

```
open(): void {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.show(EditOrderConfirmModalComponent, {
        ...NOT_CLOSABLE_MODAL_OPTIONS,
        initialState: {
            quantity: this.order!.quantity
        }
    });
    modalRef.content!.closeModal.pipe(
        takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
    ).subscribe(() => {
        modalRef?.hide();
    });
}
```

In the EditOrderConfirmModalComponent

I have this:

```
export class EditOrderConfirmModalComponent implements OnInit {

    modalService: any;
    private unsubscribe$ = new Subject < void > ();
    @Output() closeModal = new EventEmitter < void > ();
    @Input() orderToEdit ? : Order;

    constructor(
        public modal: BsModalRef,
        private router: Router,
        private location: Location,
        private service: EditOrderService
    ) {}
```

For HTML

```
<td style="min-width: 100%"> {{ orderToEdit.quantity }}</td>
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

your initial state doesn't match the interface of the component. you probably mean to do:

```
const modalRef = this.modalService.show(EditOrderConfirmModalComponent, {
    ...NOT_CLOSABLE_MODAL_OPTIONS,
    initialState: {
        orderToEdit: { quantity: this.order!.quantity }
    }
});
```